# Audio experiment with intermodulation by multiplying two analytic signals

Tags: audio, gaussian, hilbert-transform

**1) First, I describe intended processing with a basic case:**

- Let's say on left channel I have a sin wave with frequency F1, and constant amplitude A1.
- Then on right channel a sin wave with frequency F2 and constant amplitude A2.
- Then I would generate a third sin wave, with frequency F3, and constant amplitude A3. Such third sin wave verify: either  A1≤A3<=A2 or A2≤A3<=A1. Also `F3= F1+F2`.

I chose to fix A3 as  `A3= Sqrt(A1*A2)`.

The third sin wave would be blended to a **small fixed amount**  to left
   and right channels (let's say at -30 db) . This would add some *intermodulation*.

In our particular basic case, I can get the target third sin wave by multiplying analytic signals of left and right. (Context:  Analytic signals are related to Hilbert transform . I use a FIR).

Let's say on left I have  **`re1 + i*im1`**, then on right **`re2 + i*im2`** .

Then I can get my third sin wave by computing (two square roots applied on denominator) :

> (re1*re2 - im1*im2) / √√(asq1*asq2)

Asq1 is the "absolute square" for left signal i.e :

> asq1= re1<sup>2</sup> + im1<sup>2</sup>

Same story with asq2.

You might ask , why not do a straightforward "ring modulation", by multiplying directly both channels, i.e `re1*re2` . Because it will introduce an additional harmonic with frequency `Abs(F1-F2)` that I don't want.

**2) Pushing the experiment to true audio content:**

Ok, I understand that the audio effect I imagined might be flawed, or that I might be using the Hilbert Transform in a wrong way.

Nevertheless here are few improvements I've made to the implementation of this process:

- The frequency response from the Hilbert FIR is not completely flat, and is like a wide bandpass. So I ensured to reproduce same frequency response for the real part of each analytical signal.
- I avoid aliasing by upsampling 2x, analytic signals, and then downsampling after multiplication.
- The division by the term √√(asq1*asq2) introduces lot of unwanted frequencies. I've mitigated this by applying a gaussian blur to asq0, and asq1.

The division by the term √√(asq1*asq2), remain problematic even after applying some blurring. But I want the amount of distortion to be independant of the level of original signal, so I  keep it.  In other  words, if I adjust the volume, the added distortion will vary in a linear way. Not instantly, but on "average" with time .

The subjective quality of the result, vary with audio content,  the blurring period of asq0 & asq1, and also the length of hilbert FIR. It mostly affect the perception of transients (I remind that the "intermodulation" is blended to original audio, at low level).

Anyways it's an **audio experiment**.  I could have played instead by adding some second harmonic distortion. It can be pleasing, and it's often used by musicians. But I imagined something different. Hopefully, this looks enough simple.

**Now, if you  could point out what's wrong in this processing effect, or how it could be improved, that would be great.**

Comment: Intermodulation occurs when the signal goes through a non-linear system, modeled as $y(t) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k x(t)^k$. As far as I can see you don't need any Hilbert transformer. Have you tried this approach?

Comment: I might have been misusing the word intermodulation. But the model you suggest takes signal from one input, while I want to combine two input to generate a single output (then I blend). For instance, if you have 3000 hz on left, and 4000 hz on right, then a frequency of 7000 hz is generated. I skip the amplitude part (it's on my description) . Can't see how this model could do that. When talking of full audio content I just want a "natural extension" to basic case (doesn't matter exactly what the process does, but I assume all freq combinations between left and right).